# How to boost individual documents

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-2.0

I have a pretty complex query and now I want to boost some documents that fulfill some criteria. I have the following simplified document structure and I try to give some documents a boost based on the id, genre, tag.

```
{
  "id": 123,
  "genres": ["ACTION", "DRAMA"],
  "tags": ["For kids", "Romantic", "Nature"]
}
```

What I want to do is for example

```
id: 123 boost: 5
genres: ACTION boost: 3
tags: Romantic boost: 0.2
```

and boost all documents that are contained in my query and fit the criteria but I don't want to filter them out. So query clause boosting is not of any help I guess.

Edit: To make if easier to understand what I want to achieve (not sure if it is possible with elasticsearch, no is also a valid answer).

I want to search with a query and get a result set. In this set I want to boost some documents. But I don't want to enlarge the result set or filter it. The boost should be independent from the query.

For example I search for a specific tag and want to boost all documents with category 'ACTION' in the result set. But I don't want all documents with category 'ACTION' in the result set and also I don't want only documents with the specific tag AND category 'ACTION'.

Comment: If it was you to up the Answer could you please accept it?  Thank you.

Comment: It wasn't me. :)

Comment: I see.  I've tried to update the answer based on your edit, which I did not fully understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution and it was pretty simple. I use a boosting query. I now just nest the different boosting criteria with and my original query is now the base query.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/query-dsl-boosting-query.html

For example:

```
{
  "query": {
    "boosting": {
      "positive": {
        "boosting": {
          "positive": {
            "match": {
              "director": "Spielberg"
            }
          },
          "negative": {
            "term": {
              "genres": "DRAMA"
            }
          },
          "negative_boost": 1.3
        }
      },
      "negative": {
        "term": {
          "tags": "Romantic"
        }
      },
      "negative_boost": 1.2
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to have Dynamic boosting during query time.

The first matches the id title with boost and second one matches the 'genders' ACTION.

```
    {
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "title": {
              "query": "id",
              "boost": 5
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match": { 
            "content": "Action"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

If you want to have `multi_match` match based on your query:

```
{
  "multi_match" : {
    "query": "some query terms here", 
    "fields": [ "id^5", "genders^3", "tags^0.2" ] 
  }
}
```

Note: the ^5 means boost for the title.

**Edit:**
Maybe you are asking for different types of multi_match queries (at least for ES 5.x) from the ES reference guide:

**best_fields**

> (default) Finds documents which match any field, but uses
>   the _score from the best field. See best_fields.

**most_fields**

> Finds documents which match any field and combines the _score from
>   each field. See most_fields.

**cross_fields**

> Treats fields with the same analyzer as though they were one big
>   field. Looks for each word in any field. See cross_fields.

**phrase**

> Runs a match_phrase query on each field and combines the _score from
>   each field. See phrase and phrase_prefix.

**phrase_prefix**

> Runs a match_phrase_prefix query on each field and combines the _score
>   from each field. See phrase and phrase_prefix.

More at: [ES 5.4 ElasticSearch reference](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html#_literal_fields_literal_and_per_field_boosting)

Comment: But this would also enlarge my result set. For example I want to search for some tag and boost all documents with this tag and category 'ACTION' but I don't want all documents with category 'ACTION' and I don't want only documents with the tag AND category 'ACTION'. Neither should nor must will help in this case.

Comment: @Peter The answer has two parts.  Did you actually try the `multi_match`?  That boosts individual fields - you can read more at the reference - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html#_literal_fields_literal_and_per_field_boosting